# R data.table: changing the value of a variable over a specific number of dates conditionally

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set in which I'm tracking the dates a patient has specific symptoms
The data set looks like the following :

```
 ID    Date         symp    wt    ht  sympTY   sympDays   
 1     1/05/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA 
 1     1/06/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/07/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/08/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/09/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/10/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/11/2012    1       23    15   1        3          
 1     1/23/2015    NA      27    19  NA        NA
 2     2/17/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/18/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/19/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/20/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/21/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA      
 2     2/22/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/23/2014    1       17    22  0         2
 2     2/22/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/23/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/24/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/25/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/26/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/27/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/28/2016    1       20    30  1         5
 2     3/17/2017    NA      25    32  NA        NA
```

I want to create a new variable `sympfl` that tracks each day an individual has symptoms

```
    additional info that may be pertinent : 
    symp - whether a patient has symptoms within the last week
    sympTY - whether a patient had these symptoms today or yesterday
    sympDays - the number of days the patient had these symptoms within the         
    past week
```

Conditions for new `sympfl` variable:

if `symp == 1` and `sympTY == 1`, then `sympfl == 1` starting on the present date going back the number `sympDays` column holds

if `symp == 1` and `sympTY == 0`, then `sympfl  == 1` starting 2 days prior to the present date and going back the number the `sympDays` column holds

The new data set would ideally look like the following:

```
 ID    Date         symp    wt    ht  sympTY   sympDays  sympfl
 1     1/05/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 1     1/06/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 1     1/07/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 1     1/08/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 1     1/09/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1
 1     1/10/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1
 1     1/11/2012    1       23    15   1        3         1        
 1     1/23/2015    NA      27    19  NA        NA        NA
 2     2/17/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 2     2/18/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 2     2/19/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 2     2/20/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1
 2     2/21/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1   
 2     2/22/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 2     2/23/2014    1       17    22  0         2         NA
 2     2/22/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 2     2/23/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        NA
 2     2/24/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1
 2     2/25/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1
 2     2/26/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1
 2     2/27/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA        1
 2     2/28/2016    1       20    30  1         5         1
 2     3/17/2017    NA      25    32  NA        NA        NA
```

I know in order to do this, I can use an if statement, but I'm uncertain how to do this over a number of rows by dates. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @akrun I was able to solve it, thanks! This is the next step in processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data.table solution which reproduces the expected result for the given sample dataset:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, Date := lubridate::mdy(Date)][
  order(ID, -Date), sympfl := {
    if (!is.na(first(symp))) {
      tmp <- rep(NA_integer_, .N); 
      replace(tmp, 1 + seq((1 - first(sympTY)) * 3, length.out = first(sympDays)), 1)
    }}, by = cumsum(!is.na(symp))][]
```

> ```
>     ID       Date symp wt ht sympTY sympDays sympfl
>  1:  1 2012-01-05   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
>  2:  1 2012-01-06   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
>  3:  1 2012-01-07   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
>  4:  1 2012-01-08   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
>  5:  1 2012-01-09   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
>  6:  1 2012-01-10   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
>  7:  1 2012-01-11    1 23 15      1        3      1
>  8:  1 2015-01-23   NA 27 19     NA       NA     NA
>  9:  2 2014-02-17   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
> 10:  2 2014-02-18   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
> 11:  2 2014-02-19   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
> 12:  2 2014-02-20   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
> 13:  2 2014-02-21   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
> 14:  2 2014-02-22   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
> 15:  2 2014-02-23    1 17 22      0        2     NA
> 16:  2 2016-02-22   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
> 17:  2 2016-02-23   NA NA NA     NA       NA     NA
> 18:  2 2016-02-24   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
> 19:  2 2016-02-25   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
> 20:  2 2016-02-26   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
> 21:  2 2016-02-27   NA NA NA     NA       NA      1
> 22:  2 2016-02-28    1 20 30      1        5      1
> 23:  2 2017-03-17   NA 25 32     NA       NA     NA
>     ID       Date symp wt ht sympTY sympDays sympfl
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("
 ID    Date         symp    wt    ht  sympTY    sympDays   
 1     1/05/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA 
 1     1/06/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/07/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/08/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/09/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/10/2012    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 1     1/11/2012    1       23    15   1        3          
 1     1/23/2015    NA      27    19  NA        NA
 2     2/17/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/18/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/19/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/20/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/21/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA      
 2     2/22/2014    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/23/2014    1       17    22  0         2
 2     2/22/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/23/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/24/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/25/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/26/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/27/2016    NA      NA    NA  NA        NA
 2     2/28/2016    1       20    30  1         5
 2     3/17/2017    NA      25    32  NA        NA ")
```